# Objetos JSON vacios en Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, validación

Tengo una consulta, me gustaria saber como validar si un objeto JSON es vacio o no, intente hacerlo con "undefined" o null pero como soy nuevo en esto no estoy seguro si asi esta correcto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
var v = {"Mail":"hola@dominio.com","Copy":"", "cdd":"cdd@dominio.com"}
if( v.cdd !== undefined){
    if(typeof(v.Mail) === 'string'){
        if(typeof(v.Copy) === 'string' || v.Copy !== ""){
            if(typeof(v.cdd === 'string' || v.cdd !== "")){
                console.log("Todo bien")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No creo que este muy bien, si por favor me puede decir si como solucionarlo o brindarme un ejemplo lo agradeceria mucho.

Gracias.

Comment: Generalmente utilizo lo siguiente: 
if( v.cdd ) { // Haz tus cosas }
Para validar si:
1 - Existe esa propiedad
2 - Es diferente de undefined
3 - Es diferente de null
4 - No es vacío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var url = {"Mail":"hola@dominio.com","Copy":"", "cdd":"cdd@dominio.com"};

function isEmpty(obj) {
for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        return false;
}
return true;
}

function GetEmptyProperties(obj) {
for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      if(!obj[key]){
        alert("vacia la propiedad "+key);  
      }
    }            
}
}

if(isEmpty(url)) {
  alert("Tu JSON es vacio");
} else {
  GetEmptyProperties(url);
}
```

Comment: Hola! Yo necesito que me diga si cada objeto es vacio o no, ahi deberia de decirme que Copy esta vacio :(

Comment: He editado mi respuesta si el objeto esta vacio te muestra el mensaje: "Tu objeto esta vacio "sino esta vacio te muestra que propiedades del objeto no estan definidas

Comment: Hola @java005, ¿te refieres al Copy del ejemplo?, Copy es una propiedad del objeto JSON, no el objeto JSON en sí. Sin embargo por tu comentario entiendo que deseas conocer si Copy está o no vacío. Quizás deberías de modificar un poco la pregunta (solo una sugerencia :)), porque Rastalovely ha respondido la pregunta perfectamente (en mi opinión), tal y como está formulada. ¿Deseas comprobar solo las propiedades del objeto? ¿o deseas comprobar también las propiedades de las propiedades, de forma recursiva? Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, de igual manera ya solucione el problema! 

Muchas gracias!!